# parsing jade forms with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, parsing, pug

I'm not sure how to go about getting a user selected item from a dropdown list. My jade code is pretty short:

```
extends layout

block content
  p This is the CSV page
  p <select>
    <option value="domain">Domain</option>
    <option value="test">Test</option>
    <option value="random">Random</option>
    <option value="databases">Databases</option>
  </select>
  form(action="/csvuploader", method="post", enctype="multipart/form-data")
    label(for="payload") Select a file to upload:
    input#payload(type="file" name="myFile" accept="/*")
    br
    button#upload Upload
```

using some busboy methods in my /csvuploader file referenced in the 'action' part of the file upload form I have successfully saved the file. How can I now access the value selected from the dropdown list just before it?

Apologies if this sounds like a really stupid question, I'm new to node.js and forms. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the `<select>` to inside the `<form>` element, and also give it a name:

```
form(action="/csvuploader", method="post", enctype="multipart/form-data")
  p This is the CSV page
  p
    select(name = "dropdown")
      option(value="domain") Domain
      option(value="test") Test
      option(value="random") Random
      option(value="databases") Databases
  label(for="payload") Select a file to upload:
  input#payload(type="file" name="myFile" accept="/*")
  br
  button#upload Upload
```

After that, you can read the value of the dropdown from `req.body.dropdown`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however req.body.dropdown returns undefined in the console. Would it have anything to do with busboy that I'm using?

Comment: @user2412643 I assumed you would be using [`express-busboy`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-busboy), which will populate `req.body`. If you use "plain" busboy, you need to use `busboy.on('field', ...)`.

Comment: I'm using connect-busboy. The only issue is, I already have `req.busboy.on('file', ...` to save the file that is passed from the form. Will this complicate things? @robertklep

Comment: @user2412643 no that won't be a problem